# XPath for XML created by OSM, Overpass API

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm so lost. I've spent almost the entire day trying to figure this problem out and I would be so grateful for your help.

I have a hundred XML files, created via Overpass API. They each contain numerous 'nodes' each node is hold different city names and other data I don't need right now.

For the moment I am only interested in the city 'name's listed in each XML and would like to import them into a single Google Sheet cell as a list.

An example of one node, within one XML file:

```
    <osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API 0.7.54.13 ff15392f">
    <note>
    The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.
    </note>
    <meta osm_base="2018-03-23T14:17:02Z"/>
    <node id="123456" lat="42.4646033" lon="14.2139199">
    <tag k="name" v="Pescara"/>
    <tag k="name:it" v="L'Aquila"/>
    <tag k="old_name" v="Aquila degli Abruzzi"/>
    ...
```

So I've dowloaded each xml file, and I was thinking of extracting the city names using via Google Sheet's =IMPORTXML

However- I have spent the entire day trying to work out how to play nice with 'scraping' XML when the same element appears numerous times.

example

```
        <tag k="name" v="Pescara"/>
        ...
        <tag k="name" v="Rome"/>
```

So here's my formula. A truly sad state for almost a day's work.

Please help me in the right direction.

Remember, there are multiple "name" elements within each XML doc, ideally these should be comma separated.

Possible?

My embarrassing code so far-

```
=IMPORTXML("http://mywebsite.com/dir/file.xml", "//osm/meta/node/tag[@k=name]")
```

Comment: if you juste do `"//node/tag[@k=name]"`, what does it give you?

Comment: thank you @Liora - I get "imported content is empty". eek.

Comment: It seems that you are not recieving the xml, are you sure you wrote the right url?

Comment: the url does work, yes. perhaps I don't understand the full path that has to be added.. ie. //osm/meta/node/tag  ... is that required (have updated OP with more detailed code)

Comment: Wait, what happends if you add `"` around name? like [@k='name']`

Comment: @Liora, thanks for your help. so  ...xml", "//node/tag[@k='name']"  - fails also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167436/discussion-between-liora-haydont-and-callum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want all the elemens that have the k="name", you can query on that, `//*[@k='name']` and then add the `/@v` to get the v proprety

```
=IMPORTXML("http://mywebsite.com/dir/file.xml", "//*[@k='name']/@v")
```